# An error occurred while Internet Connection Sharing was being enabled

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet, windows-services

I want to share my lan internet connection over my hosted network. But it's being failed due to `An error occurred while Internet Connection Sharing was being enabled...`

I found [this post](http://ratatouille90.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/unable-to-share-computers-internet-connection-ics-problem/) but all the services mentioned there are running and windows firewall is on too.

> **Method 1:** May be that, not all the services that run Internet
>   Connection Sharing (ICS) are enabled. I’d suggest you to make sure the
>   below dependency services are enabled.
> **Refer the following steps:**
>   a. Click Start, Run, type services.msc, and click OK.
>   b. To enable a service, find it, double click it.
>   c. Make sure its startup Type is set to Automatic and service 
>   status to be started and click OK.
>   
> **All the following services must be configured in order to use ICS:**
>   a. Application Layer Gateway Service
>   b. Network Connections
>   c. Network Location Awareness (NLA)
>   d. Plug And Play
>   e. Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
>   f. Remote Access Connection Manager
>   g. Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
>   h. Telephony
>   After verifying and/or configuring
>   Automatic startup for each of these services, close the Services
>   window and restart the computer before attempting again to enable ICS.
>   **You may refer:** Using ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)
>   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing
>
> **Method 2:** Based on my online research, the issue seems to occur on
>   computers that have Windows Firewall disabled. Windows Firewall
>   service has to be running even if you’re using another antivirus and
>   firewall program on your computer. I’d recommend you to check for the
>   status of the “Windows Firewall” service and set it to “Automatic”.
>   **Follow these steps:**
>   a. Click “Start”.
>   b. Type “services.msc” in the Start search box and hit “Enter”.
>   c. Right-click “Windows Firewall” and click “Properties”.
>   d. In the “General” tab, select “Automatic” under the “Startup type”.
>   e. Click “Start” to start the service.
>   f. Click “Apply” and “OK”. Restart the computer and check if the issue
>   gets fixed.

How can I diagnose it?

Comment: I've inserted your linked data into your question, please don't use links in this way, if the link breaks your question becomes way too broad to stay open.